# Use Machine Learning to predict when a Gas Station is running out of fuel

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

We have years of data on several Gas-Stations.

**Data about the Gas-Stations**:
the number of tanks, Gallons per tank, Location, number of pumps, kind of fuel, etc.

**Data on fuel consumption for x gas station**:
Time-Date when filled, Time-Date when empty

**Data about consumers**:
Gas Price, Peak hours for gas charging, peak seasons for gas charging,

And more of this kind of data, we still need to cure, and clean.

We are always predicting which gas-station will run out of gas next, so we can dispatch a truck to reload the gas-station. 
Gas-station with an empty tank is what we need to avoid.

We are limited to finding patterns and we are hoping some kind of ML algorithm, AI service will be able to improve our prediction accuracy.

What would be the best approach to setting an ML environment that could predict:

Wich Gas Station needs to refuel next?

Could we use some of the preexisting algorithms in Google or AWS?

Thanks!

---

Ok so I am now reading about:
Linear models
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/linear-learner.html

Machine Learning to predict when a gas station will run out of fuel.

Comment: I suggest reading about [time series analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series).  There's *lots* written about the subject.

Comment: Ok so can implement a  Linear Regression Model... I wonder if there is an out of the box solution for this?

Comment: I don't know.  Requests for software packages, tools, etc. are off-topic on this site.

Comment: I am looking at regression problems. Thanks! Linear models could be the answer.

Comment: @misrajitas Is there any way this dataset is available publically? May be after anonymization.

Comment: @ShaswatRungta Is a huge load, we are trying to curate the dataset, if we can make it public I will be happy to post it here, but it won't happen any time soon. Sorry =(